# string split considering quotation

Tags: python, string, split

Imagine this string:

```
"a","b","hi, this is Mboyle"
```

I would like to split it on commas, unless the comma is between two quotations:
i.e:

```
["a","b","hi, this is Mboyle"]
```

How do I achieve this? Using split, the "hi, this is Mboyle" gets split as well!

Comment: your string is syntactically incorrect. do you mean `s = '"a","b","hi, this is Mboyle"'`?

Comment: 'yes, you are right!. It is the outputo of a gzip.open

Answer (score 3):

You can split your string not by commas, but by `","`:

```
In [1]: '"a","b","hi, this is Mboyle"'.strip('"').split('","')
Out[1]: ['a', 'b', 'hi, this is Mboyle']
```

Answer (score 2):

My take on the problem (use with caution!)

```
s = '"a","b","hi, this is Mboyle"'
new_s = eval(f'[{s}]')
print(new_s)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'hi, this is Mboyle']
```

EDIT (safer version):

```
import ast.literal_eval
s = '"a","b","hi, this is Mboyle"'
new_s = ast.literal_eval(f'[{s}]')
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` would be much safer

Comment: You have right, I haven't known about that until now. TIL :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

```
with gzip.open(file, 'rt') as handler:
    for row in csv.reader(handler, delimiter=","):
```

This makes the trick! Thank you to you all

Answer (score 1):

You could include the quotations in the split, so with `.split('","')`. Then remove the quotations on the end list items as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
s = '"a","b","hi, this is Mboyle"'
new_s = list(map(lambda x:x[1:-1], re.split('(?<="),(?=")', s)))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'hi, this is Mboyle']
```

However, `re.findall` is much cleaner:

```
new_result = re.findall('"(.*?)"', s)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'hi, this is Mboyle']
```